# How to get the equalent of python [:-1] in django ORM?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am writing a Django application where I want to get all the items but last from a query. My query goes like this:

```
objects = Model.objects.filter(name='alpha').order_by('rank')[:-1]
```

but it throws out error:

> Assertion Error: Negative indexing not supported.

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Most (if not all) SQL dialects do not support selecting all but the last record, at least not without some "tricks". That being said, one record is typically not really that much overhead, so you can first convert it to a list, like `list(Model.objects.filter(..).order_by(..))[:-1]`.

Comment: does the last item have some distinguishing feature?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get the first element and the last element using django , Location.objects.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202726/how-to-get-the-first-element-and-the-last-element-using-django-location-object)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [QuerySet.last()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#last) to get the last and use its id for excluding it from results.

```
objects = Model.objects.filter(name='alpha').order_by('rank')
last = objects.last()
objects = objects.exclude(pk=last.pk)
```

A query for excluding from the result all objects ranked with the minimum value found in DB:

```
objects = Model.objects.annotate(
    mini_rank=Min('rank'),         # Annotate each object with the minimum known rank
).exclude(
    mini_rank=F('rank')            # Exclude all objects ranked with the minimum value found   
)
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**

Django does not support negative indexing on QuerySets. Please read https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13089 for more information.

The quick and "dirty" way to do it is to convert the Queryset as a list and then use the negative indexing.

`objects = list( Model.objects.filter(name='alpha').order_by('rank') )[:-1]`

**Please do note that the objects variable is no longer a queryset but a list.**

However i would recommend using [.exclude()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters) method.

If you wish to use the .exclude() method, which i recommend, I would like to ask you to read the solution @RaydelMiranda has wrote below.

Comment: There is the last method from QuerySets. No need to convert the result into a list. Besides, try to convert qs to list just as the last resource, there is a cost in performance there.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda I know it isn't the best fix but i only showed that it is possible to remove the last item in the way he wanted to use it. If you'll continue reading, you'll see that i recommend a different method for excluding or removing the object that he does not wish to see in his QuerySet.

Comment: The way he wanted to use it, is not possible, Django does not support slices on `-1`. You've to convert a queryset, to a list first, and in the other part of the answer, you show how to exclude an object, but not the last after ordering by `rank` as he wanted.

Comment: Ah, i see what you mean by  `you show how to exclude an object, but not the last after ordering by rank as he wanted.`. Complete agree with you. I'll edit  my answer.

Comment: Good, now is a more useful answer, +1.

Answer (score 0):

Negative indexing is not allowed in Django.
However you can use negative indexing in order_by function and take the first or any number of objects in the order.
You can do something like this:

```
objects = Model.objects.filter(name='alpha').order_by('-rank')[n:]
```

Here `n` suggests the number of objects you will need. In your case it would be:

```
objects = Model.objects.filter(name='alpha').order_by('-rank')[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    query=model.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    if query.exists():
        query=query.last()
```

Comment: You may want to add some text along with your answer; not just code.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! When you answer a question you should include some kind of explanation, like what the author did wrong and what you did to fix it. I'm telling you this because your answer has been flagged as low-quality and is currently being reviewed. You can [edit] your answer by clicking the "Edit" button.